# Custom transactional emails on user signup with wp_add_user

Tags: forms, wp-login-form

I've created a front-end form that handles creation of a user using `wp_add_user` and was wondering how I could send a welcome email to the user email that they entered into the form, upon form success.

Is there a way to do this without a plugin? Or a slick plugin that fits perfectly for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sure!  Use the user_register filter (see here https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register ). You can call a custom function that will 'fire' after the user is added to the database. Your function would send out an email, perhaps.

Place the filter in your Child Theme's `function.php` file (you want to use a Child Theme so that your changes don't get overwritten/killed by a theme update).

You could place it in your own special-purpose plugin - a simple plugin without settings that just runs. Put the filter in your plugin, and your done!  (A special-purpose plugin is good for all sorts of things you want to do to your site, and doesn't require modifying the functions.php file.) Learn about developing plugins here https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/ .

Comment: I see! And how would I send out an email, do you have a starting point for this besides the firing of it?

Comment: PHP has a mail() function you could use. You could also use the WordPress wp_mail function. Here's a tutorial that might help get you started: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/wp-mail/ . There's also this from the WP Development pages: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ . Either should get you started.